# typeORM: "message": "Data type \"Object\" in \"..." is not supported by \"postgres\" database."

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, typeorm, reflect-metadata

Given the following entity definition:

```js
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @Column({ nullable: true })
  name!: string | null;
  
  @Column()
  age!: number;
}
```

The following error appears:

```sh
typeORM:   "message": "Data type \"Object\" in \"User.name" is not supported by \"postgres\" database."

...

name: 'DataTypeNotSupportedError',
  message:
   'Data type "Object" in "User.name" is not supported by "postgres" database.' }
```

When looking at the build, I see that the metadata that's emitted by TS addresses it as object:

```js
__decorate([
    typeorm_1.Column({ nullable: true }),
    __metadata("design:type", Object)
], User.prototype, "name", void 0);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I found an answer to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64635617/how-to-set-a-nullable-database-field-to-null-with-typeorm)

Answer (score 55):

You need to provide a data type explicitly.

```
@Column({ type: 'varchar', nullable: true })
name: string | null;
```

Comment: This needs to be marked as the answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you, you saved a lot of my time, I was confused because I wasn't getting any error but "Connection is not established with mysql database"

Answer (score 12):

The issue stems from this part right here:

```
@Column({ nullable: true })
name!: string | null;
```

When creating a union type, the reflected type will be `Object`.
An easy way to overcome it will be to do something like:

```
@Column({ nullable: true })
name?: string;
```

Comment: Does the DB return `undefined` if the `name` is null? Is that something that TypeORM ensures to be consistent?
If it returns `null` instead, this could seak in some errors. Doing `name === undefined` will be fine for the compiler, but if the actual value is `null` during runtime, the check will not guard from `name` being `null`.

Comment: If `name` is null in the database, it will come back as `null` in the entity. So the correct type is `string | null`, not `string | undefined`.